# Bamboo Pipeline Slack Messaged depending on status

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, devops, pipeline, bamboo

I am trying to automate some slack Messages at the end of my daily Bamboo Pipeline runs.

What I am trying to figure out is, if there is a way to check for the pipeline status and post a message to Slack reflecting that?

i.e. if the pipeline fails I'd want a fail message, and vice versa.

I haven't found a way to retrieve the status of the pipeline inside of the script

Any ideas welcome.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a hidden undocumented variable that can be used to check for failure of the current job.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## bamboo does not catch some script failures unless this flag is set

set -e

TASK="CHECK BUILD STATUS"

echo ================== START $TASK ==================

## bamboo_jobFailed is a boolean
BUILD_STATUS=${bamboo_jobFailed}
echo "BUILD_STATUS_failed?: $BUILD_STATUS"

text=$"@here Hi all! There will be a delay in the Superset data refresh today, we are looking into it :slightly_smiling_face: Thank you!"

if [[ "$BUILD_STATUS" == "false" ]]
then
    echo "the build is passing"
else
  echo "the build has failed"
  curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data "{\"text\" : \"$text\"}" https://hooks.slack.com/services/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
fi

echo =================== END $TASK ===================
```